# I have to click twice before my state is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

So basically, I'm trying to render a table dynamically from the results gotten from an API call based on some search parameters after the click of a button. My problem is that when I first input the search parameters and click the search button, it works just fine, but when I update the search parameters and click on search, it shows the old data, meanwhile, in my console, I can see that my redux state has been updated. I'll then have to click the search button once more before the table is updated.

My code

```
const queryResult = useSelector(
    (state) => state.certificateReducer.queryResult,
  );
  const [query, setQuery] = useState([]);
onFinish=()=>{
setQuery(
      queryResult?.map((item) => {
        return {
          actualId: item.id,
          id: 1,
          certificateNo: item.certificateNumber,
          oldCertificateNo: item.oldCertificateNumber,
          accountNo: item.holderCscsAccountNumber,
          oldAccountNo: item.oldHolderCscsAccountNumber,
          shareHolderName: item.holderName,
          holderAddress: item.holderAddress,
          clientCompany: item.issuingCompanyName,
          shareVolume: item.volumeOfBonds,
          isSelected: false,
        };
      }),
    );
}
const handleClick = (event) => {
    let a = [...query];
    a.map((item) => {
      if (item.id == event.target.value) {
        item.isSelected = !item.isSelected;
      }
    });
    setQuery(a);
  };
```

where I render the query:

```
 {query?.map((item, j) => {
                    return (
                      <tr key={j}>
                        <td>{item.id + j}</td>
                        <td>{item.certificateNo}</td>
                        <td>{item.oldCertificateNo}</td>
                        <td>{item.accountNo}</td>
                        <td>{item.oldAccountNo}</td>
                        <td>{item.shareHolderName}</td>
                        <td>{item.holderAddress}</td>
                        <td>{item.clientCompany}</td>
                        <td>{item.shareVolume}</td>

                        <td>
                          <Button
                            value={item.id}
                            onClick={handleClick}
                            style={{
                              cursor: 'pointer',
                              background: '#299F9E 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box',
                              borderRadius: '50%',
                              height: '30px',
                              width: '30px',
                              padding: '2px',
                              justifyContent: 'center',
                            }}>
                            <img src={NavigationMore} alt="" />
                          </Button>
                        </td>
                        {item.isSelected ? (
                          <MoreActions
                            handleSelected={handleSelected}
                            handleModal={handleModal}
                          />
                        ) : null}
                      </tr>
```

Comment: Hey Andrew, using the index as key is highly discouraged, I see you have an id field, so maybe you should use that

Comment: would be nice if you make a working example

Comment: @JenaroCalviño Thanks. will do that